# Can enum represent string numbers?

Tags: c#

I want a user to input "Sun" and have that represent "1".

```
Console.Write("Enter a Day: ");
day = Console.ReadLine();
```

can enum do this?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

```
enum Days { Sun = 1, /*...*/ }

string day = Console.ReadLine();

Days d = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), day);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=VS.100).aspx) (and [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx) as of .NET 4) to parse a string to an enum value:

```
Day day = (Day) Enum.Parse(typeof(Day), "Sun");
```

or

```
Day day;
if (Enum.TryParse<Day>("Sun", out day))
{
    // Success!
}
```

It's still somewhat ugly, mind you - there's a certain amount of casting involved in the first call, and the second wouldn't stop you from trying to parse to *any* value type.

The final reason I don't really like `Parse`/`TryParse` is that they will parse string representations of the numeric values of the enums - so "1" would successfully parse, even though it's clearly not the *name* of an enum value. That seems a bit clunky to me.

There's a nicer (IMO!) approach if you use [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/), a small open source project I wrote to allow generics with enum constraints. Then you'd have:

```
Day day = Enums.ParseName<Day>("Sun");
```

or

```
Day day;
if (Enums.TryParseName<Day>("Sun", out day))
{
    // Success!
}
```

No casting, and you can't accidentally use it on a non-enum type. (There are various other goodies in the project, of course... description parsing etc.)

Comment: plus one purely for the gratuitous plug :) and of course your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `enum`, lets say:

```
enum SkyObjects
{
   Sun = 1,
   Star = 2
}
```

You can then have the following:

```
SkyObjects day = Enum.Parse(typeof(SkyObjects ), Console.ReadLine());
```

This will have `Sun`, represented as `1` as you like.

Answer (score 0):

or,... another candidate for an immutable value type struct that "appears as" and "behaves" like an enumeration, but has additional fuinctionality as required by your domain model concerns... Using the type defined below you can write

```
 var myDay = (InPutDay)"Sunday";
```

or, ...

```
 int x = (int)InPutDay.Sun;
```

or,

`int x = (int)  InputDay.Parse("Sunday");`

Use this type:

```
   public struct InPutDay
   {
       private int val;
       private bool isDef;
       private InPutDay( )  { } // private to prevent direct instantiation 
       private InPutDay(int value) { id=value; isDef = true; } 

       public bool HasValue { get { return isDef; } } 
       public bool isNull{ get { return !isDef; } } 

       public static InPutDay Null = new InPutDay(); 
       public static InPutDay Sun = new InPutDay(1); 
       public static InPutDay Mon = new InPutDay(2); 
       public static InPutDay Tue = new InPutDay(3); 
       public static InPutDay Wed = new InPutDay(4); 
       public static InPutDay Thu = new InPutDay(5); 
       public static InPutDay Fri = new InPutDay(6); 
       public static InPutDay Sat = new InPutDay(7); 

       public static InPutDay Parse(string s)
       {
           switch (s.ToUpper().Substring(0,3))
           {
               case "SUN": return InPutDay.Sun;
               case "MON": return InPutDay.Mon;
               case "TUE": return InPutDay.Tue;
               case "WED": return InPutDay.Wed;
               case "THU": return InPutDay.Thu;
               case "FRI": return InPutDay.Fri;
               case "SAT": return InPutDay.Sat;
               default return InPutDay.Null;
           }
       }
       public static implicit operator int(InPutDay inDay)
       { return val; }
       public static explicit operator InPutDay (int inDay)
       { 
           if (inDay > 0 && inDay < 8)
              return new InPutDay(inDay);
           // either throw exception ....
           throw new ArgumentException(
               "InPutDay integer values must be between 1 and 7.");
           // or return null instance
           return InPutDay.Null;
       }
       public static explicit operator InPutDay (string inDayName)
       {  return InPutDay.Parse(inDayName); }               
  }
```